# Is every proposition on Cartesian geometry provable on synthetic Euclidean geometry?

Tags: geometry, logic, euclidean-geometry, axioms

Obviously everything that is associated with coordinates can’t be analyzed within synthetic geometry. But existence, measure and incidence statements are provable; since Cartesian geometry is an Euclidean geometry, we know that every statement on Euclidean geometry is provable — but is the reverse true?
For example, the Euclidean plane satisfies all the projective geometry postulates, but there are finite projective geometries - so not all Euclidean geometry propositions are provable within projective geometry. Does the same apply to Cartesian and Euclidean geometries?

Comment: What do you mean by "synthetic geometry"?  Do you have some specific axiom system in mind?  And what exactly do you mean by "Cartesian geometry"--what is your definition of a "proposition on Cartesian geometry"

Comment: Have you looked at the [Wikipedia article on synthetic geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_geometry)? As it says there, the distinction between synthetic and coordinate geometry is not really precise and axiomatisations of geometry like those of Hilbert and Tarski give what are arguably synthetic presentations of what I believe you mean by Cartesian geometry (i.e., geometry defined by taking points to be vectors of real numbers).

Comment: @Eric, I do not have a specific system in mind. By synthetic geometry I’m taking a logical system with points and lines as undefined elements, incidence and measure relations and axioms describing how those point, lines and structures created from them relate.

Comment: A Cartesian geometry is the geometry where a point is any element of $\Bbb R^n$ and a line is any subset  $S$ of $\Bbb R^n$ such that if $a,b,c$ are elements of $S$ then $a-b$ = $k(c-b)$ for some real $k$, with usual addition, negation and multiplication of real vectors.

Comment: You've defined synthetic geometry as a logical system and Cartesian geometry semantically, so you're not comparing like with like. The systems of Hilbert and Tarski are logical systems intended to be sound for geometries like your Cartesian geometry. I think you would gain a lot from reading the Wikipedia page I cited and the references therein.

Comment: Sorry but I’m really not finding those informations in the page.

Comment: I’ve read the entire article and still nothing.

Comment: Back again to this question. I'm asking if Cartesian geometry, as a model, has the class of all its theorems identically to the class of all the theorems of any model to the Euclidean geometry.